# AWS Glue: Keep partitioned column as value in row after writing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Does anyone know whether it's possible to tell the Glue writer to keep the column you're partitioning on in the actual dataframe?

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/work-with-partitioned-data-in-aws-glue/

> Here, $outpath is a placeholder for the base output path in S3. The
> partitionKeys parameter can also be specified in Python in the
> connection_options dict:

```
glue_context.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame = projectedEvents, 
    connection_options = {"path": "$outpath", "partitionKeys": ["type"]}, 
    format = "parquet")
```

> When you execute this write, the type field is removed from the
> individual records and is encoded in the directory structure.

I would like to keep the `type` field in the individual record.

Answer (score 3):

I am not 100% sure if it possible to tell Glue to keep the column, but in the meantime you could use this workaround:

```
projectedEvents = projectedEvents.withColumn("type_partition",projectedEvents["type"])
        
glue_context.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
                   frame=projectedEvents,
                   connection_options={"path": "$outpath", "partitionKeys": ["type_partition"]}, 
                   format="parquet"
             )
```

Comment: Good shout. Thanks!